# Why am I getting very small number as CNN prediction?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, image-classification

I created a CNN using Tensorflow to identify pneumonia and sometimes it returns a very small number as a prediction. why is this happening?

[I have attached the link for the dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/namindusanchila/x-ray/data)

Here I how I process and load the data.

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator( rescale = 1.0/255. )
val_datagen  = ImageDataGenerator( rescale = 1.0/255. )
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator( rescale = 1.0/255. )

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/kaggle/input/chest-xray-pneumonia/chest_xray/chest_xray/train/',
                                                    batch_size=20,
                                                    class_mode='binary',
                                                    target_size=(350, 350)) 

validation_generator =  val_datagen.flow_from_directory('/kaggle/input/chest-xray-pneumonia/chest_xray/chest_xray/val/',
                                                         batch_size=20,
                                                         class_mode  = 'binary',
                                                         target_size = (350, 350))
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('/kaggle/input/chest-xray-pneumonia/chest_xray/chest_xray/test/',
                                                         batch_size=20,
                                                         class_mode  = 'binary',
                                                         target_size = (350, 350
```

And here the Model, compile and fit functions

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    # Note the input shape is the desired size of the image 150x150 with 3 bytes color
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(350, 350, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2), 
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'), 
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    # Flatten the results to feed into a DNN
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(), 
    # 512 neuron hidden layer
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'), 
    # Only 1 output neuron. It will contain a value from 0-1 where 0 for 1 class ('cats') and 1 for the other ('dogs')
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')  
])
```

compile the model

```
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop

model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001),
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

model fit

```
history = model.fit(train_generator,
                              validation_data=validation_generator,
                              steps_per_epoch=200,
                              epochs=2000,
                              validation_steps=200,
                              callbacks=[callbacks],
                              verbose=2)
```

The evaluation metrics as followings, loss: 0.2351 - accuracy: 0.9847

The prediction shows a very small number for the negative pneumonia, and for positive it shows more than .50.

I have two questions:

1. why I get a very small number as `2.xxxx * 10e-20`?
2. why I can't get the following values as null?

   ```
   val_acc = history.history[ 'val_accuracy' ] 
   val_loss = history.history['val_loss' ]
   ```

Comment: 2*10e-20 is not negative. You need to look for scientific notation.

Comment: @Frightera yes it is not, I have edited my question. Thank you for the your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I see that there is no problem with your code, neither with the results you get.

This is a binary classification problem (2 classes: Positive or negative pneumonia), and the output of your model is one neurone giving values between 0 and 1.

So if the output is higher than 0.5, this means positive pneumonia. Otherwise, when you have a very small value like `2 * 10e-20` this means that it's negative pneumonia.

For your second question, you are not supposed to have accuracy and loss values to be null simply because the model is well trained and has 98% accuracy on training data.

Comment: history= model.fit(), the history object doesn't have either val_accury/val_acc or val_loss. This is why I mentioned it hasn't values.

Comment: @NaminduSanchila, could you please add the output of `val_acc = history.history[ 'val_accuracy' ] val_loss = history.history['val_loss' ]` to the question.

Comment: It is shows error, `---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_35/1406712358.py in <module>
      6 #-----------------------------------------------------------
      7 acc      = history.history['accuracy']
----> 8 val_acc  = history.history['val_acc']
      9 loss     = history.history['loss']
     10 # val_loss = history.history['val_loss']

KeyError: 'val_acc'`

Comment: The very first epoch is shows  like this`200/200 [==============================] - 68s 303ms/step - loss: 0.3897 - accuracy: 0.8739 - val_loss: 1.0525 - val_accuracy: 0.6875`  then after epochs it didn't shows val_acc and val_loss

Comment: @NaminduSanchila Please **focus** your question (edit it if necessary) to a single clear issue; as is, it is difficult to see what *exactly* your question is about, given also that you seemed to confuse very small numbers for negative ones. "*why I can't get the following values as null?*" does not read like "*I can't get `val_acc` and `val_loss` values*", as you seem to imply in your comments here.

Comment: Yes, there are two quetions.